# Error 1 Method must have a return type Vurtual Function

Tags: c#, types, return, virtual

what is this error i m new in this help

```
namespace Vurtual_Function
{
    class First 
    {
        public virtual show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class First");
        }

        class Second:First 
        {
            public override show()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class Second");
            }
            public static void Main()
            {
                Second obj = new Second();
                obj.show();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Error: Error  1   Method must have a return type      10  24  Vurtual Function

Comment: Hint: you missing the `void` on the overriden method...

Comment: (Both on the initial declaration and the override.)

Comment: namespace virtual_fun_1
{
    class First
    {
        public virtual show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class First");
        }
        class Second:First
        {
            public void print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Second class");
            }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Second obj = new Second();
            obj.show();
            obj.print();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}}
same error here

Answer (score 2):

1- You should notice that *inheritance* doesn't mean `sub class`, but means `extending` the parent (base) class. Therefore you should declare the child one in a seperate file, unless you really want it to be a sub class of the parent.

2- All Methods **MUST** have a return type, regardless whether they are `virtual`, `override`, `sealed`, `static`, ...

3- In C# traditions, public methods should start with a capital letter.

```
namespace Vurtual_Function
{
    class First 
    {
        public virtual void Show() // --> Missing return type (void assumed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class First");
        }
    }

    class Second : First 
    {
        public override void Show()  // --> Missing return type (void assumed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class Second");
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
           Second obj = new Second();
           obj.Show();
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
     }
}
```